# Retrieve object from set in O(1)

Tags: python, data-structures

All the people's names are unique. How can I find the `peter` instance in O(1)? I'm thinking you need to access peter via its hash but am unsure how to specifically do it

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self))
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
john = Person('john', 20)
jack = Person('jack', 25)
peter = Person('peter',30)

people = {john, jack, peter}

# Return peter instance
# e.g.
print(next(person for person in people if person.name == 'peter'))
```

Comment: This looks like a job for a dict with names as keys, not a set.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah true

Answer (score 1):

sets can be thought of as an unordered collection of keys of a map (read dictionary) but without any auxiliary (associated) values. you'd usually use sets to check if some value is inside the set or not, but not to retrieve that value from the set nor to access its associated values (like maps - in python dictionaries).

as @user2357112 has pointed out, you're probably looking for dictionary to find an associated value by the key - in your case name in constant time O(1)